# I want to post a list of JSON values to a model's field in Django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I want to post a movie into the collection's movie field( list of movies).
I define the model as

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    # collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete = models.CASCADE) #, related_name='reviews'
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genres = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key = True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    movie = models.ForeignKey(Movie, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title
```

this is how i am using the viewset

```
class CollectionViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = models.Collection.objects.all()
    serializer_class = serializers.CollectionSerializer
```

but i am not able to enter values for the movie field
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EGH1N.png)

also my serializer

```
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = '__all__'
```

Comment: Add your serializer please.

Comment: @Guillaume added ...

Comment: What are you writing in the movie field ?

Comment: something like  "movie": [{
                "title": "House of Horrors", 
                "description": "An unsuccessful sculptor saves a madman", 
               "genres": "Horror,Mystery,Thriller", 
               "uuid": "388c99da-0cba-4ff0-a528-faea153b43c3",
},]

Answer (score 1):

By default, DRF will represent the relationship with a [`PrimaryKeyRelatedField`](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/relations/#primarykeyrelatedfield), thus expecting a movie ID.

To achieve what you want (create an instance of movie with a collection), you need to overwrite the foreign key field in your serializer with your own Movie serializer.

```py
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = '__all__'

class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
     movie = MovieSerializer()
     class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = '__all__'

     def create(self, validated_data):
         movie = validated_data.pop('movie')
         movie = Movie .objects.create(**movie )
         collection = Collection.objects.create(movie=movie, **validated_data)
         return collection
```

You need to overwrite the create method so when creating a Collection, you also create a movie.

However, I am not sure the foreign key is set in the right model in your model. (a movie belongs to many collection but not the other way around?) If that's not what you want, just reverse the logic for the serializer.

Edit:

Sending the following should work fine:

```
{ "uuid": "1001",
  "title": "Action", 
  "description": "Action Movies",
  "movie": { "title": "The Burkittsville 7",
             "description": "The story of Rustin Parr.",
             "genres": "Horror",
             "uuid": "5e904"
            }
 }
```

The only problem as I mentionned earlier is in your model you defined the foreign key field in collection. So it expects **one single movie instance** and not a list, thus I took off the brackets you put around movie. Maybe you should consider setting the foreign key in the Movie model, or use a Many to many relationship.

Comment: I am using the API which gives the HTML form to enter the values.  how do i call the create function

Comment: You don't need to do anything. DRF will automatically call it when it saves the serializer (when you post the data).

Comment: so when i post ``` {
    "uuid": "1001",
    "title": "Action",
    "description": "Action Movies",
    "movie": [{"title": "The Burkittsville 7", "description": "The story of Rustin Parr.", "genres": "Horror", "uuid": "5e904",}]
} ``` i get the error  "detail": "JSON parse error - Expecting property name enclosed in double quotes: line 5 column 128 (char 208)"

Comment: so i guess it is looking for a primary key i.e a movie object must exist. however i want to add it from scratch

Answer (score 0):

```
#models.py
class Movie(models.Model):
    # collection = models.ForeignKey(Collection, on_delete = models.CASCADE) #, related_name='reviews'
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    genres = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

class Collection(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    uuid = models.CharField(max_length=200, primary_key = True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    movie = models.ManyToManyField(Movie, on_delete = models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self): 
        return self.title

serializers.py:
class MovieSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Movie
        fields = '__all__'
class CollectionSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    movie = MovieSerializer(read_only=True, many=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Collection
        fields = '__all__'
```

hope this will give you better unserstand this will work for you

Comment: doing this removed the text field in the api view.

Comment: you don't need to change anything just apply this logic and check you will get a list of movies

Comment: oh... actually i want to add the movie . lets say i am making the collection from scratch, i need to be able to add certain values myself